# Can't get multiple .xls file into multiple sheets of a .xls file with python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm tryin to find a way to put multiple .xls files into a single one .xls with separated sheets. (So 1.xls will go under Sheet1, etc.)
Here's my code

```
    mypath = raw_input("Please enter the directory path for the input files: ")

from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
textfiles = [ join(mypath,f) for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) and '.txt' in  f]

def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False        

import xlwt
import xlrd

style = xlwt.XFStyle()
style.num_format_str = '#,###0.00'  

for textfile in textfiles:
    f = open(textfile, 'r+')
    row_list = []
    for row in f:
        row_list.append(row.split('\t'))
    column_list = zip(*row_list)
    workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
    worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('Sheet1')
    i = 0
    for column in column_list:
        for item in range(len(column)):
            value = column[item].strip()
            if is_number(value):
                worksheet.write(item, i, float(value), style=style)
            else:
                worksheet.write(item, i, value)
        i+=1
    workbook.save(textfile.replace('.txt', '.xls'))

import glob, os
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\forpythonscript\minonna.xls')

i=1
for xlsfile in glob.glob(os.path.abspath('C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\forpythonscript\*.xls')):
    df = pd.read_excel(xlsfile)
    df.to_excel(writer, 'sheet%s' % i)
    i +=1

writer.save()
```

Here's the error while run it into anaconda.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\provaimport.py", line 51, in 
    writer.save()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 1423, in save
    return self.book.save(self.path)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 710, in save
    doc.save(filename_or_stream, self.get_biff_data())
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 680, in get_biff_data
    self.__worksheets[self.__active_sheet].selected = True
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment but I think its cause of two possible issues.

1. Do the saved workbooks in the folder only have a single sheet? typically with read_excel you also select a tab name to read from.
2. also have you tried setting the following

`df.to_excel(writer, 'sheet%s' % i, index=False)`

Comment: Added the index=False
Could you explain how to select a tab name to read from?

Comment: pd.read_excel(FileToRead, 'Sheet1', header=0) where Sheet1 = sheet name and header = 0 indicates there is a header (top row is column names)

Comment: Still not working. My .xls files are made by a single sheet, so Sheet1 is the default name.

My script, as it is now, is able to create an .xlsx file but still unable to write content on it.